# How to find two web objects with the same properties using JavaScript for Test Automation

Tags: javascript, html, selenium, testcomplete

I have this piece of HTML codes

[image: HTML]

I need to find those 2 objects using JavaScript so I can click() it and write some text (Test Automation).

The issue is the **id** is dynamically generated, thus can't be used because it keeps changing everytime the page loads.  Now because the id can't be used , those 2 objects looks the same without any unique identifier.

If I use this

```js
document.querySelector("input.value-restored[type='text']");
```

Then it will just find the first one.

Any idea how can I hit both objects?

Thank you.

Comment: When you want to find all objects in a DOM using JS you have to use `querySelectorAll` like:

`document.querySelectorAll("input.value-restored[type='text']")` and then you can search for a certain element by adding `[0]` (or any other number according to the amount of elements). Or `$$(SELECTOR)`.

The proper solution to your issue would be to tell whoever created that HTML to not use any IDs twice, because they are supposed to be unique. If you can't do that @Arghajit Bhattacharya solution is probably the best.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `[contains()]` to construct a xpath for these elements. As I can see the parent `span` has a stable class name which you can use.

in **JAVA**

```
WebElement firstElement = driver.findelements(By.xpath("//span[contains(@class,'form-row-ui-calender-row')]/input[@type='text']")).get(0);
WebElement secondElement = driver.findelements(By.xpath("//span[contains(@class,'form-row-ui-calender-row')]/input[@type='text']")).get(1);
```

OR use indexing with your xpath.

```
WebElement firstElement = driver.findelements(By.xpath("//span[contains(@class,'form-row-ui-calender-row')]/input[@type='text'][1]"));
WebElement secondElement = driver.findelements(By.xpath("//span[contains(@class,'form-row-ui-calender-row')]/input[@type='text'][2]"));
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks @ArghajitBhattacharya , if we want to use CSS Selector, how can we translate those codes into `By.CssSelector` ?  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Try this way.

Use indexing after complete your xpath. Inside below xpath `[2]` indicates second `input` webelement. If there are multiple input tag is available then you should use of indexing.

```
//input[@class='ui-calendar-display widget has-change-tracker value-restored'][2]
```

If you want to locate first webelement then use below xpath.

```
//input[@class='ui-calendar-display widget has-change-tracker value-restored'][1]
```

Comment: @keylogger said: "The issue is the id is dynamically generated, thus can't be used because it keeps changing everytime the page loads." so this won't help him unfortunately.

Comment: Then instead of `id` attribute, use `class` attribute with `indexing number`.I have updated my answer as well. and thanks for your response.:)

Comment: Thanks @jainishkapadia , how can we try it in Chrome console?  Is it `document.evaluate("//input[@class='ui-calendar-display widget has-change-tracker value-restored'][2]", document);` ?

Comment: @keylogger, I have used here `relative` xpath. And it does not any matter with browsers. But if you want to try it with chrome, Just open chrome browser, `Elements` tab open and hover the element that you want to locate it and then right click of element `copy-> copy Xpath` and paste it over notepad.

Comment: Please mark this answer as `Accepted`, if it's resolved your query. - Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In TestComplete, you can do this in the following way (within script):

```
  let obj = page.FindChildByXPath('//span[text()="Date to:"]/following-sibling::span/input[contains(@class, "ui-calendar-display")]', false);
  obj.Click();
```

If you are using Name Mapping, you can map this object quite reliably using the Required Children feature and access the object directly by a name from the mapping tree. Let me know if you need more details on how to create such mapping.

Comment: Thanks @DmitryNikolaev  . I may be wrong, but I thought **Required Children** means find a _non-unique object_ that has _unique children_ . But in this case, the _non-unique object_ itself is the latest child. Can **Required Children** be used for for the latest child ? Thanks.

Comment: @keylogger: Actually, you are right. There is a trick that could help in such situations, but after a better look at the HTML code, I think that it won't work in this specific case. However, the `FindChildByXPath` approach should work for you without a problem. It allows selecting an object by its label (*Date From:* or *Date to:*).

Comment: Thanks heaps @DmitryNikolaev  That `FindChildByXPath` does work well.