# how to get xpath for selenium in a page with javascript link with same name but different file?

Tags: javascript, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver, browser-automation

I am trying to get xpath for selenium to automate a certain task. There are multiple folder in a website each having edit button which only shows up when we hover mouse over it. It's a javascript link with same name but different argument i.e filename. Please find the Code below.

```
<ul class="repos-action-btns" style="display: block;">
  <li>
    <a title="Edit File Properties" class="repos-edit" onclick="javascript:edit('file','disableDistributionGroup.zip---file---9998511806353');" href="javascript:void(0);" alt="Edit File Properties"></a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

this edit button is on every file that is shown in website but with different value in argument . I want a xpath to click edi on a particular file with selenium automation.

Comment: Try to use indexing after your `xpath` complete.

Comment: could you please elaborate with example

Comment: Refer my answer of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42430168/how-to-find-two-web-objects-with-the-same-properties-using-javascript-for-test-a/42430327?noredirect=1#comment72180911_42430327

Comment: I am trying. I will let you know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the file name to locate the element with partial `onclick` attribute

```
"//a[contains(@onclick, 'disableDistributionGroup')]"
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to find something unique out of it. If you look at the entire statement, you would find that the `fileName` is unique.

So you can use any combination of `Xpaths` which contains your fileName.

Comment: can you provide your answer with your `xpath`. Just like below answer that was provide by @Guy.